# Screen Vertical Split Copy and Paste

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

I'm using screen (I've seen it commonly referred to as GNU screen, though I'm not using GNU) in gnome-terminal in Ubuntu, and I love it.  I like to use the vertical split so I can have a side-by-side view of two things.

Only problem is that if I use the mouse to select text on one side of the vertical split, it selects the text on both sides.  This means I can't effectively copy and paste text from terminal while using a vertical split in screen.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?  If there is a mouse-less solution, that would be even better.

Thanks! : D

Comment: P.S. I searched and couldn't find this question anywhere else, so hopefully it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in this Super User section:

[Copy-paste with GNU Screen with vertically-split windows on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/462652/copy-paste-with-gnu-screen-with-vertically-split-windows-on-os-x/464163#464163)

`Ctrl+Shift` and the cursor can be used to select text in just one of the vertical splits.

Hope this helps someone!